# Understanding Callable type in PHP - What does it mean?

Tags: php

```
public function aroundPlaceOrder(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $subject, callable $proceed, $cartId, $paymentMethod = null)
```

Can anyone tell me what "callable" does?

I can't find it anywhere else in the code and it's not setup like a variable like the rest inside this method.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: More generally speaking, it's a [type declaration](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration). (So is `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the type of the `$proceed` variable, which means your function accepts a callback function.

> Callbacks can be denoted by callable type hint as of PHP 5.4

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Hope it helps!!

Comment: That does help! Sorry one more question... in this context what exactly is it doing? @Nimeshka Srimal

Comment: @Supplement type hints are used to enforce types on the parameter. In this case, `$proceed` should be a function reference or an anonymous function. If you try to provide any other value of any other type, it should throw an error :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a callable (or callback) it's like a function that takes another function in argument. So per example.

```
function myFunction(Callable $myOtherFunction) {

}
```

You would this function like so:

```
myFunction(function() {

})
```